# How to resolve bug in Game Logic using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

[This site takes you to my game, which will show the bug when you click on a few of the divs with points on them.](http://debugit.bitballoon.com/)

I am making a Jeopardy-like game. When the user clicks one of the subcategory, the question pops-up successfully. User's are also able to answer the question successfully or unsuccessfully; However, after they answer the question, the logic seems to be picking up past clicks, resulting in the event handler executing the function for both the newly clicked targets and the past clicked targets. See link above for example of bug.

Please help me debug this!

```
 let showQuestion = function(id){
        $('body > #simpleModal').css('display', 'block')
        $('.modal-body > .question').text(answerQuestion[id].answer)
    }
    let clickCounter = 0
    $('.container > .questionBox').on('click', this,  function() {
        clickCounter += 1
        let id = this.id
        showQuestion(id)
        let questionAnswered = this
        $('.modal-content > button').on('click', this, function(){
            $('body > #simpleModal').css('display', 'none')
            if ($('.modal-content > input').val() === answerQuestion[id].question){
                goodJob()
                $(questionAnswered).css('background-color', 'green') 
                $(questionAnswered).off()
            } else {
                tryAgain()
                $(questionAnswered).css('background-color', 'red') 
                $(questionAnswered).off()
            }
```

I have been in a web development course for the past 2 weeks, so I am still learning. My site is a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a click listener inside of a click listener. Is there a reason for doing that? I wonder if the first one, `$('.container > .questionBox')`, is picking up the clicks inside the modal also. But I can't tell without looking at more of your code if that's why the clicks seem to be stacking up.

Comment: I needed to grab an element's id based off of it being clicked. Because "this"  is in the scope of that first click event, I nested another click event within that one. I can send the rest of my code too, if you would like to see.

Comment: Thanks, I can actually see all your code using Developer Tools. I'm a new developer also, so I may be wrong but if I was working on this I would try extracting the second onclick event from inside the first and add whatever logic and code that's needed to make it work the way you want.